# При добавлении класса не применяются стили | html, css

Tags: javascript, css, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У меня есть блок .tarif-plan__items, в нем содержится 2 блока:
.tarif-plan__months и tarif-plan__year.

При нажатии на Month или Years у меня меняются классы у детей .tarif-plan__items.
Класс .hide только добавляет стиль display: none;
Однако блок с таким классом не скрывается (внизу картинки), это можно увидеть на картинке. Никаких !important я не использую, в js коде добавляю только классы, никаких инлайновых стилей.

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: У вас же написано, что действует правило класса `tarif-plan__months` - `display: grid`. Если вы указываете правила только через селектор одного класса везде, то значит правила для класса `hide` описаны выше и по правилам *каскадности*  они переписываются последующими равноценными по специфичности или более специфичными.

Answer (score 1):

Советую прочитать про [приоритеты](https://webkyrs.info/page/prioritety-stilei-css) стилей CSS

В целом, класс .hide просто не имеет достаточного веса чтобы перебить основной стиль, CSS не выбирает его приоритетным.
Варианты решений:

- Сделать его с ключевым словом !important:

  ```
   .hide {
       display: none !important;
   }
  ```
- Сделать его более специфичным, к примеру

  ```
   .tarif-plan__items .hide {
       display: none;
   }
  ```
- Поменять расположение стилей, подробнее описано в первой ссылке